# Multivariate normal density using Woodbury matrix inversion lemma

Tags: c++, performance, matrix, eigen

I'm trying to speed up by multivariate normal density function by taking advantage of the fact that the covariance matrix is of the form A + U C U'. The inverse of such a matrix can be calculated using the [Woodbury matrix lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Woodbury_matrix_identity) that allows us to take inverses of either diagonals or much smaller matrices.

The arguments to my function are dynamically sized `Eigen::Matrix` objects. The matrices A and C are diagonal, and C is much smaller than A.

```
typedef Eigen::Matrix< double, Eigen::Dynamic, 1              > Vec;
typedef Eigen::Matrix< double, Eigen::Dynamic, Eigen::Dynamic > Mat;
const double inv_sqrt_2pi(0.3989422804014327);
const double log_two_pi (1.83787706640935);

double evalMultivNormWBDA(const Vec &x, const Vec &meanVec, const Vec &A, const Mat &U, const Mat &C, bool log)
{
    Mat Ainv = A.asDiagonal().inverse();
    Mat Cinv = C.inverse();
    Mat I =  Cinv + U.transpose()*Ainv*U;
    Mat SigInv = Ainv - Ainv * U * I.ldlt().solve(U.transpose() * Ainv);
    Eigen::LLT<Mat> lltSigInv(SigInv);
    Mat L = lltSigInv.matrixL(); // LL' = Sig^{-1}
    double quadform = (L * (x-meanVec)).squaredNorm();    
    unsigned int dim = x.rows();
    if (log){

        // calculate log-determinant using cholesky decomposition (assumes symmetric and positive definite)
        double halfld (0.0);
        // add up log of diagnols of Cholesky L
        for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i){
            halfld += std::log(L(i,i));
        }

        return -.5*log_two_pi * dim + halfld - .5*quadform;


    }else{  // not the log density
        double normConst = std::pow(inv_sqrt_2pi, dim) * L.determinant();
        return normConst * std::exp(-.5* quadform);
    }
}
```

For 9-dimensional vectors it's actually slower than the function I have that doesn't take advantage of the lemma. How can I make this faster?

Here is the generic multivariate normal density function along with some rough timing code. Even for vectors of dimension 100 it's slower.

```
double evalMultivNorm(const Vec &x, const Vec &meanVec, const Mat &covMat, bool log)
{
    // from Eigen: Remember that Cholesky decompositions are not rank-revealing. 
    /// This LLT decomposition is only stable on positive definite matrices, 
    // use LDLT instead for the semidefinite case. Also, do not use a Cholesky 
    // decomposition to determine whether a system of equations has a solution.
    Eigen::LLT<Mat> lltM(covMat);
    double quadform = (lltM.matrixL().solve(x-meanVec)).squaredNorm();
    size_t dim = x.rows();
    if (log){

        // calculate log-determinant using cholesky decomposition too
        double ld (0.0);
        Mat L = lltM.matrixL(); // the lower diagonal L such that M = LL^T

        // add up log of diagnols of Cholesky L
        for(size_t i = 0; i < dim; ++i){
            ld += std::log(L(i,i));
        }
        ld *= 2; // covMat = LL^T

        return -.5*log_two_pi * dim - .5*ld - .5*quadform;


    }else{  // not the log density
        double normConst = std::pow(inv_sqrt_2pi, dim) / lltM.matrixL().determinant();
        return normConst * std::exp(-.5* quadform);
    }

}

typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock Clock;


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    auto begin = Clock::now();


    unsigned int size(100);
    unsigned int numiters(1e5);
    Vec x = Vec::Random(size);
    Vec mean = Vec::Zero(size);
    Mat U = Mat::Random(size,1);
    Mat C = Mat::Identity(1,1);
    Mat Amat = Mat::Identity(size,size) * .01;
    Vec Avec = Vec::Constant(size,.01);
    Mat cov = U * C * U.transpose() + Amat;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < numiters; ++i){
        evalMultivNorm(x, mean, cov, true); // 134 milliseconds with ten, 1588 with 50, 7718  100
        //evalMultivNormWBDA(x, mean, Avec, U, C, true); // 368,  2687 with 50, 15583 with 100
    }






    auto end = Clock::now();
    std::cout << "Delta t2-t1: " 
              << std::chrono::duration_cast<std::chrono::milliseconds>(end - begin).count()
              << " milliseconds" << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you post the original function as a reference?

Comment: @Frank you mean the one that doesn’t make use of the lemma that I’m kind of comparing it to? Sure

Comment: Can you add some example inputs to your post as well?

Comment: Is it also slower if you don't evaluate intermediate results? I.e. don't store things in `Mat` variables, except for `L`. You can try using `auto` for intermediate results instead, that will store everything as the template expression types that Eigen uses internally. Be wary about the pitfalls associated with that though (https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/TopicPitfalls.html). As a test you could try putting the entire calculation for `L` on a single line and see if that gives a speedup.

Comment: Use 'using' rather than typedefs.

Comment: @Darhuuk yeah that helps a little bit but it's still much slower than the standard function

Comment: @Taylor What about the speed difference when you use a large matrix? Large meaning e.g. 50000 x 50000.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hesitate to write this as it's not about the code obove but about a different algorithm. However I think, for small enough m (eg a quarter of n -- here A is nxn and B is mxm), that this is faster.

The below is in terms of upper cholesky factors, ie an upper triangular matrix U so that

```
U'*U = P
```

Of course this is just the transpose of the lower factor.

We want to find a cholesky factor of the inverse of

```
Cov = A + M*B*M', 
where A and B are diagonal and M is nxm
```

We can write

```
Cov = (A + M*B*M') = A + Sum{ k in [0,m-1] | v[i]*b[i]*v[i]'}
where the v[i] are the columns of M
```

To find U define U(i) to the the cholesky factor of the inverse of

```
A + Sum{ k in [0,i] | v[i]*b[i]*v[i]'}
```

then a little algebra shows

```
U(i+1)'*U(i+1) = inv( A + Sum{ k in [0,i+1] | v[i]*b[i]*v[i]'})
               = inv( A + Sum{ k in [0,i] | v[i]*b[i]*v[i]'} + v[i+1]*v[i+1]')
               = inv( inv( U(i)'*U(i)) + v[i+1]*v[i+1]')
               = U(i)'*inv( I + w*w'/beta)*U(i)
where w = U(i)*v[i] and beta = 1/b[i]
```

So if we can find Z so that

```
Z'*Z = inv( I + w*w'/beta)
```

we will have

```
U(i+1) = Z*U(i)
```

It may seem that no progress has been made -- we have to do m factorisation and multiply up the results -- but in fact Z can be computed simply, and so can the products.

We note, by Woodbury, that

```
inv( I + w*w'/beta) = I - w*w'/(beta + w'*w)
```

and that, somewhat surprisingly, Z is given by

```
Z[k,k] = sqrt( N(k+1)/N(k))
Z[k,i] = - w[k]*w[i]/(sqrt( N(k)*N(k+1)))   i>k
```

where

```
N(i) = beta + Sum{ k>=i | w[k]*w[k]}
Note N(i) = N(i+1) + w[i]*w[i]
and  N(0) = beta+w'*w
```

For example, for the diagonal:

```
(Z'*Z)[i,i]     = Sum{ k<=i | Z[k,i]*Z[k,i]}
        = Z[i,i]*Z[i,i] + Sum{ k<i | Z[k,i]*Z[k,i]}
        = N(i+1)/N(i) + w[i]*w[i]*Sum{ k<i | w[k]*w[k]/(N(k+1)*N(k))}
        = N(i+1)/N(i) + w[i]*w[i]*Sum{ k<i | (N(k)-N(k+1))/(N(k+1)*N(k))}
        = N(i+1)/N(i) + w[i]*w[i]*Sum{ k<i | 1/N(k+1) - 1/N(k)}
        = N(i+1)/N(i) + w[i]*w[i]*(1/N(i) - 1/N(0))
        = (N(i+1) + w[i]*w[i])/N(i) - w[i]*w[i]/N(0)
        = 1 - w[i]*w[i]/(1+w'*w)
```

and the off diagonal case is similar

To compute Z*U we have:

```
Let y[k] = w[k]/(sqrt( N(k)*N(k+1)))

(Z*U)[i,j]  = Sum{ k | Z[i,k]*U[k,j]}
        = Sum{ i<=k<=j | Z[i,k]*U[k,j]}
        = Z[i,i]*U[i,j] + Sum{ i<k<=j | Z[i,k]*U[k,j]}
        = Z[i,i]*U[i,j] + Sum{ i<k<=j | - w[i]*w[k]/(sqrt( N(i)*N(k+1)))*U[k,j]}
        = Z[i,i]*U[i,j] - w[i]*Sum{ i<k<=j | w[k]*U[k,j]}/(sqrt( N(i)*N(i+1)))
        = Z[i,i]*U[i,j] - y[i]*Sum{ i<k<=j | w[k]*U[k,j]}

Let R[i,j]  = Sum{ i<k<=j | w[k]*U[k,j]} then
R[j,j]      = 0
R[i,j]      = w[i+1]*U[i+1,j] + R[i+1,j]
and
(Z*U)[i,j]  = Z[i,i]*U[i,j] - y[i]*R[i,j]
```

Thus incorporating another vector into U is of order n*n

Note that the initial step is a little different in that we want to find U so that

```
U'*U = inv( A + x*b*x' }
```

with A diagonal. Similar reasoning to the above leads to

```
Let M(i) = beta + Sum{ k>=i | a[k]*x[k]*x[k]}
Note M(i) = M(i+1) + a[i]*x[i]*x[i]
and  M(0) = beta+x'*a*x
where a[i] = 1/A[i]
U[i,i]  = sqrt( a[i]*M[i+1]/M[i])
U[i,j]  = sqrt( a[i]/(M[i+1]*M[i])) * x[i]* a[j]*x[j]
```

An implementation, that I believe works, is below. The matrices are in column order. The ws parameter is workspace, 4*C doubles (though only C doubles are used in the second routine). 
Note that v is assumed to have dimension C, while really U is CxC, but
could be stored in a RxC array. If you are using square matrices set R to be C.
The function mat_ut_vec( R, C, U, v, w);
computes U*v (for upper triangular U) in w.

```
void    mat_utspec_cholesky_update( Int R, Int C, double b, const double* x, double* U, double* ws)
{
double* y = ws;
double* d = y+C;
double* S = d+C;
double* v = S+C;
Int i, j;

    mat_ut_vec( R, C, U, x, v);

double  N;
double  pN = 1.0/b;
    for( i=C-1; i>=0; --i)
    {   N = pN + v[i]*v[i];
    double  t = 1.0/sqrt( N*pN);
        y[i] = v[i]*t;
        d[i] = pN*t;
        pN = N;
    }

    for( j=0; j<C; ++j)
    {   S[j] = 0.0;
        for( i=j-1; i>=0; --i)
        {   S[i] = S[i+1] + v[i+1]*U[i+1+R*j];
        }
        for( i=j-1; i>=0; --i)
        {   U[i+j*R] = d[i]*U[i+j*R] - y[i]*S[i];
        }
        U[j+j*R] *= d[j];
    }
}


void    mat_utspec_acholesky( Int R, Int C, double b, const double* v, const double* A, double* U, double* ws)
{
double* y = ws;
double* z = ws+C;
Int i, j;
double  N;
double  pN = 1.0/b;
double  alpha;
    for( i=C-1; i>=0; --i)
    {   alpha = 1.0/A[i];
        z[i] = alpha*v[i];
        N = pN + z[i]*v[i];
    double  t = sqrt( alpha/(N*pN));
        y[i] = -v[i]*t;
        U[i+R*i] = pN*t;
        pN = N;
    }

    for( j=0; j<C; ++j)
    {   for( i=0; i<j; ++i)
        {   U[i+j*R] = z[j]*y[i];
        }
    }
}
```